# Linq query with 3 tables

Tags: c#, linq

Can you please let me know how to write a LINQ from for the following SQL query,

```
Select cr.Id 
from [dbo].[User] usr, [dbo].[LikesStaging] lk, [dbo].[ChangeRequestStaging] cr 
where usr.CustomerId=lk.[LikedBy] and usr.[Id] = 'user' and lk.[ChangeRequestId] = cr.[Id]
```

Was trying with the following query, but was not able to add `usr.[Id] = 'user'` condition in my linq query.

```
var result = from usr in lstUser
             join lk in lstLikeStaging
             on usr.CustomerId equals lk.LikedBy
             join cr in lstChangeRequests
             on lk.ChangeRequestId equals cr.Id
             select new
             {
                 cr.Id
             };
```

Please let me know how to add this condition here.

Comment: aren't you missing some joins in the SQL query?

Comment: He's doing old-style joins in the `where` clause of his query.

Comment: @Manju - Did any of the answers below help you to understand and/or solve the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from usr in lstUser
join lk in lstLikeStaging on usr.CustomerId equals lk.LikedBy
join cr in lstChangeRequests on lk.ChangeRequestId equals cr.Id
where usr.id=="user"
select new
{
 cr.Id
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result = from usr in lstUser
                     where usr.Id == "user"
                     join lk in lstLikeStaging
                     on usr.CustomerId equals lk.LikedBy
                     join cr in lstChangeRequests
                     on lk.ChangeRequestId equals cr.Id
                     select new
                     {
                         cr.Id
                     };
```